# Google authentication with http.Redirect

Tags: go, ssl, redirect, https, oauth-2.0

I am trying to implement google authentication using Go.
The code is working fine if I am running a single service which talks to googleoAuth URL.
But I am facing when I am trying to use HTTP.Redirect.
Basically the idea is on receiving a particular URL the first service should redirect the request to some other service which takes care of Google authentication completely.
I am running both services on my same system on two different ports.
Both the server are running as secured server with **self signed certificate**.

Here are the codes I am using.

main() function for both servers, only the port numbers are different.

```
func main(){
    //Declare the Mux for the server
    fmt.Println("Starting service")
    mux := handlers.New()
    setupHandlers(mux)
    certFile := flag.String("certfile", "../cert/certbundle.pem", "certificate PEM file")
    keyFile := flag.String("keyfile", "../cert/server.key", "key PEM file")
    flag.Parse()


    server := http.Server{
    Addr: "127.0.0.1:8080",
    Handler: mux,
    TLSConfig: &tls.Config{
        MinVersion:               tls.VersionTLS13,
        PreferServerCipherSuites: true,
        },
    }
    server.ListenAndServeTLS(*certFile, *keyFile)
}
```

Here is the redirection code

```
func New() *http.ServeMux{
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    // Root
    //mux.Handle("/",  http.FileServer(http.Dir("templates/")))
    mux.HandleFunc("/", loginPageHandler)
    mux.HandleFunc("/internal", internalPageHandler)

    // OauthGoogle
    mux.HandleFunc("/auth/google/login", oauthGoogleLogin)
    mux.HandleFunc("/auth/google/callback", oauthGoogleCallback)

    return mux
}

func loginPageHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.Redirect(w, r, "https://127.0.0.1:8087/",  http.StatusMovedPermanently)
}
```

Here are the codes for handling google authentication

```
func loginPageHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        tmpl, err :=  template.ParseFiles("templates/login.html")
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
        err = tmpl.Execute(w, nil)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
}

func oauthGoogleLogin(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    // Create oauthState cookie
    oauthState := generateStateOauthCookie(w)

    /*
    AuthCodeURL receive state that is a token to protect the user from CSRF attacks. You must always provide a non-empty string and
    validate that it matches the state query parameter on your redirect callback.
    */
    u := googleOauthConfig.AuthCodeURL(oauthState)
    http.Redirect(w, r, u, http.StatusTemporaryRedirect)
}

func generateStateOauthCookie(w http.ResponseWriter) string {
    var expiration = time.Now().Add( 1 * time.Hour)

    b := make([]byte, 16)
    rand.Read(b)
    state := base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString(b)
    cookie := http.Cookie{Name: "oauthstate", Value: state, Expires: expiration}
    http.SetCookie(w, &cookie)

    return state
}

func oauthGoogleCallback(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // Read oauthState from Cookie
    fmt.Println("here")
    oauthState, _ := r.Cookie("oauthstate")

    if r.FormValue("state") != oauthState.Value {
        log.Println("invalid oauth google state")
        http.Redirect(w, r, "/", http.StatusTemporaryRedirect)
        return
    }

    data, err := getUserDataFromGoogle(r.FormValue("code"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err.Error())
        http.Redirect(w, r, "/", http.StatusTemporaryRedirect)
        return
    }

    fmt.Fprintf(w, "UserInfo: %s\n", data)
}
```

There are two issues observed.
First I am getting TLS error from the second service which is the destination of the redirection,  **http: TLS handshake error from 127.0.0.1:57715: remote error: tls: unknown certificate** as soon the request is redirected to the second service.

Secondly, in the func oauthGoogleCallback(),  the call r.Cookie("oauthstate") fails with no named cookie found error.

Any thought the reason behind TLS error? I believe if that can be solved then rest will work automatically.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you configure the http client with that certificate? I see the server is configured, but not the client.

Comment: I have not used http client in my code so far. I am using my browser to open https://localhost:8080/ which connects to my service running on 127.0.0.1:8080. The handler for "/" of service running at 8080 then do http.Redirect(w,r, "127.0.0.1:8087/",http.StatusMovedPermanently) .
So I am not sure which http client configuration you are suggesting. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: Note, I am using self signed certificate.

Comment: Which one is "the second service"? Which service is the one giving the cert error? And which call?

Comment: Both the services have same func main(). One running on 8080 which redirects to the service running at 8087. The service running at 8087 has the functions defined in the section "Here are the codes for handling google authentication". Once the service at 8080 redirects to service at 8087, service running at 8087 throws error message http: TLS handshake error from 127.0.0.1:57715: remote error: tls: unknown certificate

Comment: Is there a router/proxy in front of these? What is port 57715? Can you identify which call returns the cert error? Is it googleOauthConfig.AuthCodeURL? or getUserDataFromGoogle?

Comment: There is no proxy or router. As soon as this line hits "http.Redirect(w, r, "https://127.0.0.1:8087/",  http.StatusMovedPermanently)" if service running at port 8000, tls error message appears at the terminal of service running at 8087. The error comes from the function loginPageHandler() which intercepts any traffic to the route https://127.0.0.1:8087/ . Note, after this error the templates/login.html is rendered in the browser

Comment: There is nothing in `loginPageHandler` that can return that error. The error must be coming from somewhere else in the code, try to pinpoint that.